# \includegraphics[scale] makes plot figure (PDF) from smooth to serrated

Tags: graphics, scaling

I plot a function in Scilab and export to pdf image file. The pdf file looks very smooth as following.

[image]

However, when I tried to include this smooth pdf file in LaTeX. It becomes serrated like.

[image]

The code snippet I used.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.35]{hello.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a way to make it look more smooth? Should I sample smaller points of the function?

Comment: Do you have a printer? Is the bad quality present in print as well?

Comment: This looks like it's just a viewer issue. Could you try a different PDF viewer?

Comment: @pkofod Thank you. I tried it on Windows adobe reader, it looks OK. How could I never thought about that.

Comment: @Jake Could you write a answer and then I would close it. The culprit is the Document Viewer on Ubuntu. Otherwise, I have to delete this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually an issue with the PDF viewer: Some smooth the graphics using anti-aliasing, others don't. Try changing the smoothing options, or opening the document in a different viewer.

When printed, the graphics should look fine either way.